# Word splits my tables

Tags: microsoft-word

I am making some revisions to a document in Word. That document is split into sections with headers.  The last section has a paragraph followed by a table.

The revisions I am making are in the middle of the document, and every time that I go to a new line as I type, the paragraph in the last section of the document jumps down into the middle of the table, splitting the table into two parts; the first 3 rows jump above the paragraph for no reason, while the rest stays where it belongs.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your table has been given some "Absolute Positioning". To confirm and fix:

- Select the table, then right-click and choose "Table Properties..."
- Under the Table tab, at the bottom (under "Text wrapping"), I'm guessing that the "Around" button has been selected.

[image]

- Select the "None" button instead, and click OK. That should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve this by cutting the paragraph out, moving the table down the page further, then repasting the paragraph above the table.

This works but as soon as I add another line I have to do it again.  I would be interested in knowing if there is a more permanent fix to this, as I don't know how much more will be added to the document, and I'd hate to have to do this every time I add a new page.